# Pagination not shown using Joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla3.0

I have a strange problem with a rather simple Joomla 3.0 (current version, to be specific).
Category pagination is disappearing from any page other than the first one.

This is the first page of a category http://elektryk.opole.pl/z-zycia-szkoly
The second page has lost the page numbers http://elektryk.opole.pl/z-zycia-szkoly?start=10
The same story happens for every category blog view. The frontpage pagination is working fine.

The site's template is a modified Protostar template (the php code is standard, without any modifications). The site's config is to display pagination.

Any guesses? Thank you
**update:** and yes, the same happens using default templates.

Comment: As I could see by default there is a file `/templates/protostar/html/pagination.php`. Could you please check if it is not altered and try to replace it with a new downloaded from http://www.joomla.org/download.html

Comment: I have tried this one. It is being processed (the html changes), but the issues remains the same.

Comment: It's simple but please double check: `menu item -> blog layout -> pagination` setting.

Comment: Thanks, I've been through these as well, issue remains the same.

Comment: How did you solve this ??